# Android: 2 buttons in TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, tablerow

I'm pretty new to android programming.
I want to add two buttons to a tableRow programmatically.
Here is the code wich should do it, and the XML of the table row:

Code:

```
public void buttons() {
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setText("Fertig");
    Button button2 = new Button(this);
    button2.setText("Zurück");

    tableRow.addView(button1);
    tableRow.addView(button2);
}
```

XML:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >
</TableRow>
```

But if I run the code, it looks like this:
[image]

If I just add button1 (Remove `tableRow.addView(button2);` from my code), the button is at the right position, at the verry bottom left of the screen...

Can anybody help me, so both buttons will be displayed right?

Thank you! :)

Comment: post your full xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `XML` from `TableRow` to `TableLayout` and add each button into a single `TableRow` then Add your `tableRow` into your main `TableLayout` as following:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/table1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="2dp" >
</TableLayout>
```

in your Java class

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
/* Create a new row to be added. */
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,               TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("Dynamic Button");
b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Add Button to row. */
tr.addView(b);
/* Add row to TableLayout. */
//tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sf_gradient_03);
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,         TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: `FILL_PARENT` is deprecated, instead of that use `MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: Thanks for that @Shayanpourvatan, I will replace it in my code